# Unable to copy docs to /usr/share/doc ${docdir} yocto

Tags: yocto

I am working with yocto, i want to copy some documents into rootfs.
    when i copy them they are present inside 
    packages-split/Ex-doc/usr/share/doc/versions/Ex.txt

```
Now i want to copy from here into rootfs, below are the changes i have made inside recipe

do_install() {
   install -m 0755 -d ${D}${docdir}/versions
   install -m 0755 ${S}/Ex.txt ${D}${docdir}/versions
}

FILES_${PN}-doc += "${docdir}/versions"

But i am not able to see /usr/share/doc dir inside rootfs. Please point me where i am doing wrong.

Thank You
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the package FILES_${PN}-doc to the list of packages installed in the image?

Comment: Ya, i have added this line                                                                   PACKAGES = "${PN}-dbg ${PN}-staticdev ${PN}-test ${PN}-doc ${PN} ${PN}-dev ${PN}-locale"